# How to maximize XL file using QTP/UFT?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I want to maximize XL file using qtp/uft. I got few solutions but didn't work.
My code is

```
Set pixXLS = CreateObject ("excel . application")
pixXLS.Application.Visible= True
pixXLS.Workbooks.Open "C:\ Breakout Matrix.xls "
```

File get open but not in full screen mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your code to maximize:

```
pixXLS.WindowState = -4137
```

Also, refer this link for Excel Enumerated Constants:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb216429(v=office.12).aspx